# Beginner-"Undefined function 'ReadIndexndexDailyLogreturn' for input arguments of type 'cell'."-Error

Tags: matlab

I am aware many of you will think this should be easily solvable. However, I have no clue about MATLAB.

Here goes my problem: when trying to execute the following example in the Command Window through the command

```
getLogReturnExcel('ALL.xls', {'ALL'}, 37000, 38000)
```

the cell-type error appears for this function. From what I understand however, when using {} the function should be grabbing the type inside {} (String in this case?) instead of the cell itself, which would be being grabbed if we were to use (), so there should be no error? Or is there something much more elementary that I might be overseeing? Thanks in advance for every bit of help; as you can tell I very much need it.

Cheers,
Ben

Here goes the function getLogReturnExcel:

```
function [logreturn, datearray] = getLogReturnExcel( datafilename, ticker, begindate, enddate )

    [aanumber, aatext] = xlsread(datafilename);
    aaticker = aatext(:,1);
    aadate = aanumber(:,2);
    aaret = zeros(length(aaticker),1);
    aaret(1,1) = 0;
    for i = 2:length(aaret)
        aaret(i,1) = ln(aanumber(i,3))-ln(aanumber(i-1,3));
    end    

    aadate = aadate(strcmp(aaticker,ticker));
    aaret = aaret(strcmp(aaticker,ticker));

    logreturn = aaret(aadate>=begindate & aadate<=enddate);
    datearray = aadate(aadate>=begindate & aadate<=enddate);

return
```

The file 'ALL.xls' contains 3 columns, one with strings (the acronym for stocks) and two with numbers (I'm assuming double), one for the date in Excel-format and one with each day's stock standing.

Answer (score 1):

The string can be obtained by using:

```
ticker{:}
```

or else the comparison in the lines

```
aadate = aadate(strcmp(aaticker,ticker));
aaret = aaret(strcmp(aaticker,ticker));
```

will be between strings and cell array.

Here is some [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) to access elements of a cell array.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Sorry to say I have so little clue that I have to ask again, though. I tried substituting 'ticker' in those two lines with 'ticker{:}', but it still shows the same error. Did I misunderstand something? Also, I copied that comparison line from someone else, but I don't completely understand how it works, and what 'aadate' and 'aaret' attempt to access when I equal them to 'aadate(0/1)' or 'aaret(0/1)'. I would be very grateful for more help...